# Measure several line segments as one in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, measurements

I have a polyline shapefile which is divided into more than 56 pieces and I want to measure the length of the whole line as one line.

Comment: Have you tried using the Dissolve tool?

Comment: I tried but it does not meet my request , just need to tell me if there is a way to join every line in the water network alone

Comment: No, you cannot merge/join a polyline if you want to keep all the segments as separate pieces. You can either select them, as Lou says, or you can add an attribute that distinguishes them from other lines in the feature class. You can then use Statistics or Summary Statistics as needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the features separate, you can use the Statistics window to find the sum of selected features. Select the features your want to measure, then open the attribute table, right click the SHAPE_length field, and click on statistics.

Or... you can start an editing session and merge the 56 polylines into a single feature

Comment: Thank you dear Lou  but would like to ask  that tru 'Merge" the  whole lines will be together as one package I need every line to be stand alone    because I have a network of waterlines